# Insert results of stored procedure with multiple parameters into a temp table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure that requires the user to specify multiple parameters. The following script returns the correct results:

```
Execute dbo.Stored_Procedure_Name 
            @Ord1 = 1, @Ord2 = 4, @Ord3 = 5, @Ord4 = 6, @Ord5 = 7,
            @Table_Name = 'Random_Table_Name'
```

Now all I need to do is put the results into a temp table as the result set is the basis for a larger query that is setup to run off of a temp table. I've found lots of examples online of how to do this (including `OPENROWSET`) but haven't been able to locate something that leverages a stored procedure that requires multiple parameters. Other examples assume the user knows the column headers and can create a table before running the script, which I do not.

Any guidance you may be able to provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: When you say you have to put the results in a temp table, do you mean that you need to put it into a table by the name of the 6th parameter?  Can you clarify?

Comment: Incidentally, Erland Sommarskog covers this problem-space very well in this article.  Perhaps one of these solutions are what you are looking for.  http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful for you?

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real good way to get the results of a stored procedure call into a temp table. I would either convert your stored procedure to a table-valued function and return the result set (but this won't work if you don't know the structure of the table to be returned beforehand), or just have your stored procedure create the temp table itself and have your query just reference the temp table that gets created by your stored procedure. Something like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Your_Temp_Table') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #Your_Temp_Table

-- call your SP that will make the temp table #Your_Temp_Table
exec dbo.your_sp

-- use the temp table in the rest of your query
select * from #Your_Temp_Table
```